# Getting datetime from SQL Server into correct format for Redshift

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift

When I extract a timestamp column from SQL Server, it comes across like this:

```
Thu Jan 26 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

I need to get it into an acceptable Redshift format. For example:

```
2017-01-26 19:00:00
```

How do I do this kind of conversion?

Comment: How are you retrieving the value and what's the type of the column? SQL Server knows about typed values, but how things are presented as strings is up to the client. You *can* have SQL Server format the value (using `CONVERT`) but where possible, it's always a better idea to have the client do any formatting instead.

Comment: try `Convert(datetime, <column>, 103)`

Comment: is there a name for this format (Thu Jan 26 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) ) ?

Comment: "Inconvenient"? Date/time formats mostly do not have names since any random bystander can cobble together their own by combining standard parts. It slightly resembles the email time format (as described in RFC 2822), but it omits the comma after the weekday name and includes a full timezone name. The only time formats anyone who has a choice should bother with are those described by ISO 8601 (as Redshift indeed does, with `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`).

Answer (score 1):

For a timestamp column X, use the FORMAT() function while converting to DATETIME to return a VARCHAR value:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(X AS DATETIME), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss')
```

Or, you can also use CONVERT() to return a DATETIME value:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, X, 120)
```